# Christopher Priest, *The Affirmation*: "Who is Alice Dowden?"

Tags: character-identification, history, alternate-history

This is from page 160 of the Gollancz "SF Masterworks" edition (2011) of Christopher Priest's slipstream (or at any rate elusive) novel *The Affirmation* (1981).

In an alternate reality (later explored further in the short story collection *The Dream Archipelago* (2009), which I haven't read yet), one character is asking another to explain some elements of his fictional autobiography, set in our reality (which of course is alternate to theirs):

> "Who is Felicity?" [She is a character in the part of the novel set in our reality.]
>   "What are the Beatles?"
>   "Where is Manchester, Sheffield, Piraeus?"
>   "What is England, and which island is it on?"
>   "Who is Gracia, and why has she [...]?" [Slight spoiler deleted. Gracia is another character.]
>   "Who was Hitler, what war are you talking about, which cities had they bombed?"
>   "Who is Alice Dowden?"
>   "Why was Kennedy assassinated?"
>   "When were the sixties, what is marijuana, what is a psychedelic rock?"
>   "You've mentioned London again ... I thought it was a state of mind?"
>   "Why do you keep talking about Gracia?"
>   "What happened at Watergate?"

Well, who *is* Alice Dowden?
[If the answer is that she's a character later in the book, don't tell me! I'll get there soon enough.]
Incidentally, if you can tell me why Kennedy was assassinated, that would also be cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Red face.) My memory is even worse than I thought.

I thought I was certain that the name hadn't been mentioned in the book (and perhaps indeed it hasn't), but I just double-checked, and a character referred to only as "Alice" *is* mentioned - only very briefly, and in passing - on pages 23-24.

It would be in keeping of the style of the book if that was her.

So my question is not an interesting one, and I almost wish I could downvote it!

But it might be worth leaving it, in case someone else is ever puzzled by the same thing, and wastes time Googling for a fictional character (indeed a character *so* fictional that they barely exist in any sense at all).

Comment: No worries. If you get a better answer as you read the book, please update this.